# WebSocketException: 'The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.'

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, websocket

I'm working on a React application where I need to establish a WebSocket connection to a server which is in Asp .net core for file uploading purposes. The server requires authentication, and I'm attempting to pass an authentication token as a subprotocol using the useWebSocket hook from the react-use-websocket library.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useWebSocket from 'react-use-websocket';

function App() {
  const socketUrl = "ws://localhost:5204/api/v1/upload/file?projectId=102";
  const token = "my-token";

  const { sendMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket(socketUrl, {
    protocols: ['realProtocol', token],
  });

  // Remaining component code...
}
```

Here's the issue: When I attempt to establish the WebSocket connection with the authentication token passed as a subprotocol, the connection fails with the error message:

System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: 'The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.'

**However, if I remove the authentication token from the subprotocol list, the WebSocket connection is successfully established.**

I've verified that the authentication token is valid and the WebSocket URL is correct. Why does the WebSocket connection fail when passing the authentication token as a subprotocol, and how can I resolve this issue?

Here is my backend code :

```
[Route("file")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<object> UploadListOfFiles(int projectId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    // Get the value of the Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header
                    var protocolHeader = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"];
                    var token = protocolHeader.FirstOrDefault()?.Replace("realProtocol, ", "");
                    var authenticationResult = await _customJwtBearerHandler.HandleTokenAuthenticationAsync(token);

                    if (authenticationResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        var email = _customJwtBearerHandler.ExtractEmailFromToken(token).ToLower();

                        using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

                        var processedFiles = await _fileUploadClient.ReceiveFileChunks(HttpContext, webSocket);

                        List<FileUploadValidationResultModel> validationResults = await _validators.Validate(processedFiles, projectId);

                        List<ApiResponse> responses = await _fileUploadClient.ValidateAndProcessUpload(email, validationResults, projectId);

                        return responses;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                }

            }
```

Comment: `AcceptWebSocketAsync()` means you aren't expecting a sub-protocol. You need to do `AcceptWebSocketAsync(someValueHere)` although given that the server doesn't know the authentication parameters beforehand, this seems imppossible. Which is why this is a rather unusual use of subprotocol. Why don't you just rely on passing the authentication as a normal HTTP header like everyone else does? Why does it need to be in the subprotocol?

Comment: @Charlieface I don't rely on passing the authentication as a normal HTTP header like everyone else does because there is no method in the JavaScript WebSockets API for specifying additional headers for the client/browser to send.

Comment: Okay i got the answer , thanks @Charlieface.
i used this in backend and it worked
using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync("realProtocol");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling it to expect no sub-protocols

```cs
using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
```

You need to add at least one subprotocol that they will have in common.

```cs
using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync("realprotocol");
```

Exactly why the client is sending the authentication token as one of the subprotocols is unclear. It's already sending it as a normal HTTP header, so this seems unnecessary.